# create new UILabel when conditions are met looping through NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, enumerate

I have an NSArray with various parts divided by ,.

this array is much longer

```
citiesArray10000 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                            @"33.572162&-112.087966&Phoenix&Arizona",
                            @"32.154289&-110.871062&735&Tucson Arizona ",
                            @"33.401926&-111.717379&Mesa&Arizona",
                            @"33.282874&-111.854943&Chandler&Arizona",
                            nil];
```

I loop through these to see if they meet certain conditions.

```
[citiesArray10000 enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id object, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        // do something with object
        NSArray *coorArray = [object componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];
        NSString *firstString = [coorArray objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *secondString = [coorArray objectAtIndex:1];
        NSString *thirdString = [coorArray objectAtIndex:2];
        NSString *fourthString = [coorArray objectAtIndex:3];

if (fabs(crnLoc.coordinate.latitude - latitude) <= 1) {
            if (abs(crnLoc.coordinate.longitude - longitude <= 1)) {

                self.label.text = fourthString;
            }
        }
```

the labels will float on the surface of the screen depending on the coordinates of the object that meet the conditions

```
self.label.frame = CGRectMake(160,(((self.mheading-90)-β)*-5.688)+200, 30, 200);

self.label2.frame = CGRectMake(160,(((self.mheading-90)-β)*-5.688)+200, 30, 200);
```

where β has different values depending on the coordinates.

the problem is that if more than one object in the array meets the conditions I need to create another label and have it's text be the fourthString of that object.  Then when the condition isn't met any more delete that label.  Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: And where is that label? What about using a UITableView? Where should be put the other label? Above? Underit? Etc.

Answer (score 0):

How about using tag?
When you iterating through the citiesArray10000 array, I think you can add a tag to the uilabel and later on, when the conditions not meet anymore, you can find the label by the tag and delete the label.

```
[citiesArray10000 enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id object, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        // do something with object
        NSArray *coorArray = [object componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];
        NSString *firstString = [coorArray objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *secondString = [coorArray objectAtIndex:1];
        NSString *thirdString = [coorArray objectAtIndex:2];
        NSString *fourthString = [coorArray objectAtIndex:3];

if (fabs(crnLoc.coordinate.latitude - latitude) <= 1) {
            if (abs(crnLoc.coordinate.longitude - longitude <= 1)) {

                UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:idx];

                label.text = fourthString;

                // add the label to the view ...
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: i tried this but the problem I'm having that more that one label is added at a time and each has a different text, position on the screen.  How do I do that?